# Sinch Android SDK crash when receiving new instant message

Tags: android, android-ndk, instant-messaging, sinch

I'm using Sinch Android SDK for instant messaging.
I'm Receiving the below error whenever someone send me a message, the error occurred before the "onIncomingMessage" listener is called.

I'm using Nexus 5, 5.1.1 with Sinch version 3.6.2, thanks.

Logcat:

```
08-10 17:48:00.853    4933-5484/com.my.package A/libc? Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x29a in tid 5484 (Thread-14334)
08-10 17:48:00.958      187-187/? I/DEBUG? *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-10 17:48:00.958      187-187/? I/DEBUG? Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:5.1.1/LMY48B/1863243:user/release-keys'
08-10 17:48:00.960      187-187/? I/DEBUG? Revision: '11'
08-10 17:48:00.960      187-187/? I/DEBUG? ABI: 'arm'
08-10 17:48:00.963      187-187/? I/DEBUG? pid: 4933, tid: 5484, name: Thread-14334  >>> com.my.package <<<
08-10 17:48:00.964      187-187/? I/DEBUG? signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x29a
08-10 17:48:01.004      187-187/? I/DEBUG? r0 0000029a  r1 9af0bded  r2 00000054  r3 00000007
08-10 17:48:01.004      187-187/? I/DEBUG? r4 9a9704d0  r5 9a970460  r6 9a970480  r7 9a970620
08-10 17:48:01.004      187-187/? I/DEBUG? r8 9a9704ec  r9 9a9703d0  sl aefa84e0  fp aefa84e0
08-10 17:48:01.004      187-187/? I/DEBUG? ip 9af9ad70  sp 9a970388  lr 9ad215a5  pc b6df7372  cpsr 200b0030
08-10 17:48:01.004      187-187/? I/DEBUG? backtrace:
08-10 17:48:01.004      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #00 pc 00014372  /system/lib/libc.so (strcpy+5)
08-10 17:48:01.004      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #01 pc 001a85a1  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.004      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #02 pc 0025e2cc  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #03 pc 0026801c  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #04 pc 0026a640  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #05 pc 00245f54  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #06 pc 00243f50  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #07 pc 00245314  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #08 pc 00245480  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #09 pc 001ebb40  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #10 pc 001ed6c8  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #11 pc 001ec63c  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #12 pc 001ee064  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #13 pc 001ef8c0  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #14 pc 002d0e2c  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #15 pc 002d1354  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #16 pc 001abf07  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #17 pc 001af3dd  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #18 pc 001af7e3  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.005      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #19 pc 001afb91  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.006      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #20 pc 001b0621  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.006      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #21 pc 001b31f5  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.006      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #22 pc 001aee55  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.006      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #23 pc 001b8701  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.006      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #24 pc 001b7f53  /data/app/com.my.package-2/lib/arm/libsinch-android-rtc.so
08-10 17:48:01.006      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #25 pc 00016baf  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
08-10 17:48:01.006      187-187/? I/DEBUG? #26 pc 00014af3  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
08-10 17:48:02.271      187-187/? I/DEBUG? Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_01
08-10 17:48:02.271     752-5712/? W/ActivityManager? Process com.my.package has crashed too many times: killing!
08-10 17:48:02.271     752-5712/? W/ActivityManager? Force finishing activity 4 com.my.package/.ui.activities.messenger.MessengerActivity
08-10 17:48:02.271      752-822/? I/BootReceiver? Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
08-10 17:48:02.278    4933-4933/com.my.package I/Choreographer? Skipped 78 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-10 17:48:02.308     752-5712/? W/ActivityManager? Force finishing activity 4 com.my.package/.ui.activities.myapp.myappActivity
08-10 17:48:02.323     752-5712/? W/ActivityManager? Wtf, activity ActivityRecord{3652e5b u0 com.my.package/.ui.activities.myapp.myappActivity t2536 f} in proc activity list not using proc ProcessRecord{1b40577f 4933:com.my.package/u0a179}?!?
08-10 17:48:02.323     752-5712/? W/ActivityManager? Wtf, activity ActivityRecord{d075827 u0 com.my.package/.ui.activities.messenger.MessengerActivity t2536 f} in proc activity list not using proc ProcessRecord{1b40577f 4933:com.my.package/u0a179}?!?
08-10 17:48:02.323      178-178/? E/lowmemorykiller? Error writing /proc/4933/oom_score_adj; errno=22
08-10 17:48:02.329     752-5712/? I/ActivityManager? Killing 4933:com.my.package/u0a179 (adj 9): crash
08-10 17:48:02.386      752-766/? I/art? Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 134459(6MB) AllocSpace objects, 17(432KB) LOS objects, 13% free, 42MB/48MB, paused 2.489ms total 111.011ms
08-10 17:48:02.438      202-202/? I/Zygote? Process 4933 exited due to signal (11)
08-10 17:48:02.481     752-1308/? W/ActivityManager? Spurious death for ProcessRecord{1b40577f 4933:com.my.package/u0a179}, curProc for 4933: null
08-10 17:48:02.739      752-768/? W/InputMethodManagerService? Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 4933 uid 10179
08-10 17:48:02.742    1140-1140/? I/Keyboard.Facilitator? onFinishInput()
```

Here is the SinchService I'm using, I copied it from sinch sdk samples (sinch-rtc-sample-messaging) :

```
    package com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.sinch.android.rtc.*;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.MessageClientListener;
import com.sinch.android.rtc.messaging.WritableMessage;

public class SinchService extends Service {

    private static final String APP_KEY = "enter-application-key";
    private static final String APP_SECRET = "enter-application-secret";
    private static final String ENVIRONMENT = "sandbox.sinch.com";

    private static final String TAG = SinchService.class.getSimpleName();

    private final SinchServiceInterface mServiceInterface = new SinchServiceInterface();

    private SinchClient mSinchClient = null;
    private StartFailedListener mListener;

    public class SinchServiceInterface extends Binder {

        public boolean isStarted() {
            return SinchService.this.isStarted();
        }

        public void startClient(String userName) {
            start(userName);
        }

        public void stopClient() {
            stop();
        }

        public void setStartListener(StartFailedListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
            SinchService.this.sendMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
        }

        public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            SinchService.this.addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }

        public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
            SinchService.this.removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted()) {
            mSinchClient.terminate();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mServiceInterface;
    }

    private boolean isStarted() {
        return (mSinchClient != null && mSinchClient.isStarted());
    }

    public void sendMessage(String recipientUserId, String textBody) {
        if (isStarted()) {
            WritableMessage message = new WritableMessage(recipientUserId, textBody);
            mSinchClient.getMessageClient().send(message);
        }
    }

    public void addMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.getMessageClient().addMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    public void removeMessageClientListener(MessageClientListener listener) {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.getMessageClient().removeMessageClientListener(listener);
        }
    }

    private void start(String userName) {
        if (mSinchClient == null) {
            mSinchClient = Sinch.getSinchClientBuilder().context(getApplicationContext()).userId(userName)
                    .applicationKey(APP_KEY)
                    .applicationSecret(APP_SECRET)
                    .environmentHost(ENVIRONMENT).build();

            mSinchClient.setSupportMessaging(true);
            ;
            mSinchClient.setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground(true);
            mSinchClient.startListeningOnActiveConnection();

            mSinchClient.addSinchClientListener(new MySinchClientListener());
            mSinchClient.start();
        }
    }

    private void stop() {
        if (mSinchClient != null) {
            mSinchClient.stopListeningOnActiveConnection();
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }
    }

    public interface StartFailedListener {

        void onStartFailed(SinchError error);

        void onStarted();
    }

    private class MySinchClientListener implements SinchClientListener {

        @Override
        public void onClientFailed(SinchClient client, SinchError error) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStartFailed(error);
            }
            mSinchClient.terminate();
            mSinchClient = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStarted(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient started");
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onStarted();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClientStopped(SinchClient client) {
            Log.d(TAG, "SinchClient stopped");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLogMessage(int level, String area, String message) {
            switch (level) {
                case Log.DEBUG:
                    Log.d(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.ERROR:
                    Log.e(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.INFO:
                    Log.i(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.VERBOSE:
                    Log.v(area, message);
                    break;
                case Log.WARN:
                    Log.w(area, message);
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRegistrationCredentialsRequired(SinchClient client,
                ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see some code...

Comment: I added the service code i'm using, but i don't think it will help since the crash is in the SDK itself, probably it is written in C or C++ and the crash happened on strcpy as you can see in the logcat.

Comment: Duda, we would very much like to test your app. Can you mail us on support@sinch.com and give us access to either github or an apk. Also if you could supply what the message contains. It would be super helpful for us to use your keys and user id to get that message to one of our apps.